# How to fix 'The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly' error when JAVA_HOME variable is set correctly?

Tags: maven, environment-variables, java-home

I'm trying to set up a project in my new laptop. While doing so, I faced this error even though the JAVA_HOME variable is set correctly.

**Error**:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

**Environmental Variables in laptop:**

[image: Environmental Variables]

**Solutions tried so far**:

1. Almost all answers suggest declaring the JAVA_HOME variable correctly, which I have already done.
2. Ensured 'bin' is not added in JAVA_HOME variable.
3. Tried declaring JAVA_HOME via UI and via command prompt.
4. Restarted my laptop multiple times.

Any possible solution is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of your `JAVA_HOME` variable, it should only contain the directory. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: This might help other people if they encounter they same issue or a typo. If not, let me know, I can delete this.

Comment: In general, typo issues are not considered worthy to keep as they are either very localized, or almost impossible to find through search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark Rotteveel mentioned, removing the semi colon at the end fixed the error. I'm able to run maven commands now.